# add boxplot to other graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

[image]

These two graphs have exactly the same x axis value of each point, is it possible to display the box whisker on top of the first graph?

I tried this:

```
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(211)
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.plot(x7,y7,'c+-')
    ax.plot(x8,y8,'m+-')
    ax.plot(x9,y9,'g+-')
    ax.boxplot(dataset)
    xtickNames = plt.setp(ax, xticklabels=boxx)
    plt.setp(xtickNames)
```

The results only display the box whisker graph without the other three lines, so, I tried this instead:

```
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(211)
    ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(212)
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.plot(x7,y7,'c+-')
    ax.plot(x8,y8,'m+-')
    ax.plot(x9,y9,'g+-')
    ax2.set_xscale('log')
    ax2.boxplot(dataset)
    xtickNames = plt.setp(ax2, xticklabels=boxx)
    plt.setp(xtickNames)
```

But I want them to be shown in the same graph, is that possible?

Comment: They don't have the same `x` values. You changed the *labels* on `boxplot` not the *actual values*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want two graphs with comparable X and Y ranges to appear one on top of the other, you can try "Hold". For example:

```
import pylab

pylab.plot([1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]) 
pylab.hold(True) 
pylab.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: This would be better done using the OO interface an the OP used.